# HTML5 validation: JavaScript weirdness with willValidate

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

OK this is a weird one. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.

http://jsfiddle.net/wVp8j/

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type='text' required />
    <button>check field validity</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
var field = document.querySelector('input[type=text]');
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert('Validates: '+field.willValidate);
    alert('Value missing: '+field.validity.valueMissing);
}, false);
```

If the form is submitted with the field left blank, submission is suppressed, as you'd expect, but the first alert, checking the field's validity state, gives `true`. **Why?**

To contradict this further, the second alert confirms there's a problem with the field and also gives `true`, as expected.

What am I missing?

[Sidenote: MDN [seems to think](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation#Constraint_validation_process) `willValidate` is a method, not a property.]

[**EDIT**]

As the commenter below points out, `willValidate` says whether the field is a **candidate** for validation, not, despite its misleading name, whether the field will validate.

Which presumably means the only means of telling whether a field will validate, should the form be submitted, via JS, is to iterate over its `validity` object and see if any flag is set to true.

[**EDIT 2**]

Turns out you can just check `validity.valid` on a field, even though the `valid` flag doesn't show up if you `console.log` the entire validity object. This would appear to be the way, therefore, to find out whether a field will hypothetically validate.

Comment: `willValidate` is a property that says whether or not an input can be validated, not if it is valid or not, see http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/#toc-willValidate

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`willValidate` is a property that says whether or not an input **can** be validated, not if it is valid or not. The only time that `willValidate` is false is if the input element is disabled or the like.

See http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/#toc-willValidate

Use `field.validity.valid` instead to check for validity.

http://jsfiddle.net/3xFua/

```
(function() {
    var field = document.querySelector('input[type=text]');
    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
        console.log('Validates: ', field.validity.valid);
        console.log('Value missing: ', field.validity.valueMissing);
    }, false);
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation) suggests using `.checkValidity()` which

> Method    Description
>
> checkValidity()   Returns true if the element's value has no validity problems; false otherwise. If the element is invalid, this method also causes an invalid event at the element.

while (as [@soktinpk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24746808/2685386) correctly states) `.willValidate` simply flags it as available for validation, not passing validation.

Thus I recommend using this:

```
function() {
    alert('Validates: '+field.checkValidation());
    alert('Value missing: '+field.validity.valueMissing);
}
```

---

off-topic, `alert` is a terrible debugging tool. Consider using `console.log` or `debugger;`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with alert where you're simply demonstrating a problem. The idea that alert is ALWAYS wrong and evil is silly.

Comment: Yes there is. It is modal: you can't do anything on the page while it's open. That *does* make it always wrong and evil *while debugging* (or demonstrating a problem, as you put it). It should only ever be used (as its name suggests) for alerting the user to important information that they're otherwise not likely to notice

Comment: Sorry, I disagree. That is a disproportionate stance to take. We must agree to disagree.